# How to update two attributes of a single XML node using Java?

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I need to update two attributes of a single node in XML in Java form. I unable to to do that.

Need only the syntax.

***XML:-***

```
<control name="control_200" xpos="233" ypos="25" width="60" type="float" format="%7.2f" refvar="gud/_ZSFR[29]" hotlink="true">
```

*Need to update xpos and ypos on single button click.*

***Java code:-***

```
JButton btnx1y1 = new JButton(">");
        btnx1y1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    String filePath = "C:\\Users\\Admin\\workspace\\generator\\data\\f.xml";
                    File inputFile = new File(filePath);
                    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();  
                    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
                    Document document = dBuilder.parse(inputFile);

                    Node control = document.getElementsByTagName("control").item(0); 

                    NamedNodeMap attr = control.getAttributes(); 
                    Node nodeAttr = attr.getNamedItem("xpos"); 
                    nodeAttr.setTextContent(str201x);
```

**str201x is String value of xpos, I need to input str201y too for ypos.**

Comment: Please post the code.

Comment: @Addy I had added the code

Comment: @umarfaraz I had added the code

Comment: And why not follow it up with  `attr.getNamedItem("ypos").setTextContent(str201y);` ... just wondering  ???

Comment: @Addy did , not getting the result. Is this the only way ?

Comment: What is the expected result , did you try putting a break point and inspecting the "document" element (considering that you are using an IDE for this). ... Maybe the problem is using the udpated values once the xml has been modified to suit your requirements ...

Comment: @Addy Ok got it, yes using Eclipse IDE . After using (exception e) throwing and error on  `nodeAttr.setTextContent(str201x);` **showing scope must be final.**